# How to Add a Regression Head

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I am fairly comfortable using tensorflow directly (python) as well as building models with keras.  So far all the models I have built have been traditional straight through processing from the input image, through to the softmax output.  I'm actually surprised how straightforward it is.

I now want to train a model for both classification and regression.   Slide 16 of this Stanford CNN class [CS231n](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2016/winter1516_lecture8.pdf) is **exactly** what I want to do.   I'm really unclear (actually, I have NFI) how to branch the tensorflow graph, create two loss functions and properly back propagate both of them.

Can anyone point me to a code sample?   Very much appreciated.

Comment: By using the [functional](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) api

Comment: Basically, you would just use this 'model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss={'main_output': 'binary_crossentropy', 'aux_output': 'binary_crossentropy'}, loss_weights={'main_output': 1., 'aux_output': 0.2})' where you can change  'binary_crossentropy' to the name of you custom loss function if none of the standard ones work for you.

Comment: @iga how do you provide two different labels though, one class label for the classification and say, 4 integer labels for the regression head? especially if i'm using something like an ImageDataGenerator for the classification. I assume I'll probably need to write my own custom generator instead, but what format do I provide, what kind of tensor does it need to output?

Comment: You can see this tutorial for a complete example. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/04/keras-multiple-outputs-and-multiple-losses. Search for "Our next block simply kicks off the training process" in this tutorial for example of how to provide multiple "labels".

Comment: I am not sure how ImageDataGenerator affects multiple output heads. You should probably ask another question with more details.

Comment: @iga is there any methodology/best practice/standard values used for deciding the loss weight for the classification head and the loss weight for the regression head?  You used 1 and 0.2.  How did you decide these values?

Answer (score 1):

Responding to the question in the comment:

I have not worked on such problems but here are some general thoughts.

Ideally, the (shared) weights that are good for regression should also be good for classification. In this case, the `loss_weights` don't matter much as both losses should push the weights in the same direction. You should just make sure that the average magnitudes of your `loss * loss_weight` is roughly the same so that one loss is not completely ignored.

If you find that the heads are fighting, i.e. you can train a separate regression model to much higher accuracy than if it is trained together with classification, you can either branch-out the heads earlier (so that they share fewer weights and have more specialized layers for themselves) or just train two separate models. There are also a ton of research papers on multi-task training that allow you to share more weights to accomplish different tasks.